# How to use AJAX Calls With The WordPress Rewrite API (after watching this video)

Tags: ajax, wordpress

The problem is — I got the JSON response but without any interaction on page and from base of local site-name (`\\firstwp.test` — that was working fine before I start the experiment of using AJAX).

After watching the video about using AJAX Calls With The WordPress Rewrite API, I add this pretty simple code to the `\wp-includes\functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'init', function () {
    add_rewrite_tag( '%filter_id%', '([0-9]+)' );
    add_rewrite_rule( "filter/([0-9]+)/?", 'index.php?filter_id=$matches[1]', 'top' );
});

add_action( 'template_redirect', function () {
    global $wp_query;
    
    $filtered_posts = "some wp query...";
    
    if ( !empty( $filtered_posts ) )
    {
        $response = "some data from query...";
        wp_send_json_success( $response );
    }
});
```

I was thinking to be able to use this code by adding `\filter\1` to the url.
But I immediately received a JSON response from the base name of the site without any parameters and additions.
I'm just taking my first steps in WordPress and don't understand how it works there, although I've been using the "standard" AJAX features as XMLHttpRequest for a long time.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? also you should never be editing the wordpress core files (\wp-includes\functions.php)

Comment: Not sure what video you're watching to AJAX, but `template_redirect` hook is not for the AJAX things.

Comment: @Moishy thank you I always think about what `functions.php` I should to edit. Possibly it should by theme's one.

Comment: @VijayHardaha it's also baffle me. But I saw it here:
https://youtu.be/LWuLanCPoF0?t=186
and this is only video about those possibilities.

Comment: @Moishy I just have to use AJAX interaction between page and server. Get filtered products for example.

Comment: @DimAnd Ok, that video is not wrong, but that's kind of an advanced approach, and using that approach there are pros and cons, pros can be "your response might be faster", and cons will be "you'll have to handle a lot of validations, depends on rewrite rules, and you'll lose the `DOING_AJAX` validation", I will suggest if you're learning things, then start with basics and normal `wp_ajax` action hook, rather than jumping of advanced coding.